# Stop feature executions if first (only) scenario of the feature fails

Tags: c#, specflow

I have bunch of scenarios in a feature and i want to stop executing the test if first test of the feature fails. Because first test case is always TESTSETUP in my features.

For example:
Scenario: 00 TestSetUp
Scenario: 01 Successful login 
Scenario: 02 Forgot password
etc...

if Scenario:00 fails stop execution else continue execution

Comment: What is the problem with standard Assert ? Also I think it is good practise to have 1 assert by test

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the unit test runner (NUnit, XUnit, MSTest, SpecFlow+Runner) you are using and how you are executing the tests.

With the NUnit3 Console runner you have to use the --stoponerror argument. (https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line)

With SpecFlow+Runner you have to configure stopAfterFailures to 1. This works on the command line and in Visual Studio. (http://www.specflow.org/plus/documentation/SpecFlowPlus-Runner-Profiles/#Execution)

Or you could try the Runtime/stopAtFirstError value to true. This should also do it. (http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Configuration/)

Comment: I want test feature to continue execution if any test fails BUT test 01. Because all other tests are  linked to Test 01 (TestData).